# Phpunit test Facebook login in functional test

Tags: php, symfony, facebook-graph-api, phpunit, facebook-sdk-3.0

I need to test Facebook login with phpunit for a web app that I'm building. The app uses the [Facebook SDK for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/).

My app after Facebook login check the access token, url is something like this:

http://myapp.dev/login/facebook?facebookId=12345&accessToken=CAA...fkZD

Is there a way to generate a fake access token -- if so, how should I do it?

Comment: I think you had to mock the Facebook's response and test what you need! see https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects

Comment: As already suggested you should solve by mocking Facebook request or session object. Can add to the question some code you've already tried in order to let us know something more about your code structure?